# ¿ Cómo poner de color negro la barra de navigation de android típica en KITKAT?

Tags: java, android, navigation

He buscado por Internet sobre este tema y me encuentro siempre algo similar a:

`if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {`
   `getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_awesome_color));`

`}`

o `<item  name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/theme_color</item>`

Pero ambas opciones son para dispositivos 5.0 o mayor. Lo que me gustaría a mí saber es cómo lo puedo hacer para que aquellos dispositivos que sean **KITKAT** (incluído) hacia delante ponerla también negra. Porque el código que encuentro al ponerlo me dice *Android Studio* que la API minima para es 21 y yo lo quiero para el KITKAT también.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a la barra superior en la que aparece el símbolo del wifi, batería, etc?

Comment: No, a la inferior, a la de "atrás" "home" y "pestañas"

Comment: Yo tengo Android Kitkat y me aparece solo una barra. ¿Podrías agregar una captura?

Comment: Mis botones son translúcidos de serie

Comment: En whatsapp por ejemplo se me vuelve negro, yo lo que quiero es eso.

Comment: Yo quiero como en Jelly Bean , https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YCThIedqbCQ/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: He leído que no se puede... no es un problema muy grave pero bueno , no pasa nada, me conformaré, gracias Error404 de todas formas :) En lollipop creo que sí , algo es algo :)

Comment: A vale, yo es que esa barra la tengo integrada en el propio teléfono y no me aparece cuando abro las aplicaciones. Por eso no sabía a que barra de navegación te referías.